# The third part (1.0.X) of my product version number is not padded to 4 digits

Tags: wix

In my wix project the product version number is generated by a tool and we strictly want the 3rd component of the number to appear as it was generated.

Let's say the version number to use is 2.17.0043, then after the product is installed I can see it omits the leading 0s from the third component of the version showing it as 2.17.43. Even if I open the bootstrapper's outcome setup executable file Properties and switch to the Details tab page then the File or Product version are 2.17.43.

How can I preserve the 3rd part of the version to keep it's original textual look 2.17.0043?

Comment: Just did a smoke test with an MSI, and I see the zeros preserved. Is this a WiX Bundle?

Comment: I answered this in the WiX-Users mailing list.  This isn't a Windows Installer supported version format.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul, yes it's a WiX Bundle. But from what I can understand from Christopher Painter's answer it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Burn always normalizes versions as #####.#####.#####.#####. Arbitrary text like padding isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

This can serve as an answer, however, someone experienced can explain what are the differences and why does this approach work.

When I set my version in bundle.wxs then 2.17.0043 ends up to appear as 2.17.43 in Add/Remove Programs after installation. However, if I use binder variable to set the Bundle version `Version="!(bind.packageVersion.MSIPackageId)"`, where the MSIPackageId is the Id attribute value of my Chain/MsiPackage element, then that way it preserves the 3rd version part as it was set internally in my MSI package (2.17.0043).

> Stein Åsmul asked/commented to my question description above, whether I was dealing with WiX Bundle; perhaps that's the difference, that could be the trick.

In my case this is a perfect solution since I have only one MSI package under the Bundle/Chain, however, I guess if you have multiple MSI packages and the bootstrapper's generated setup exe should not inherit version number of any of the MSI packages, then this won't work, or maybe there is another way to achieve it that I'm not aware of.