# Set precision in WiX v4 generated msi

Tags: windows-installer, versioning, wix4

Setting the version in the package tag of the `package.wxs` file as `<Package ... Version="10.01.00.00"/>`
truncates the unnecessary 0s. That is in the control panel, the version displayed is `10.1.0.0`.
Is there anyway to set the precision in wix?

I have tried using a binder variable (wix variable in v4) instead as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544092
But doesn't seem to work.